# XCOPY deployment script - how to include certain files?

Tags: powershell, xcopy

I need to copy only certain parts of a folder using Powershell, specifically this list:

```
$files = @("MyProgram.exe",
           "MyProgram.exe.config",
           "MyProgram.pdb",
           ".\XmlConfig\*.xml")
```

In human readable form: 3 specific `MyProgram.*` files under root of target folder and all XML files under `XmlConfig` folder which itself is under root of source path (`..\bin\Release\` in my case). `XmlConfig` folder must be created in destination, if it does not exist.

**What I have tried:**

(1) I tried the following, but it did not work, i.e. no folder or files were created at the destination path:

```
Copy-Item -Recurse -Path "..\bin\Release\" -Destination ".\Test\" -Include $files
```

(2) When `-Include` is removed, whole folder structure is successfully created, including subfolders and files:

```
Copy-Item -Recurse -Path "..\bin\Release\" -Destination ".\Test\"
```

It must be something wrong with my understanding of how `-Include` filter works:

(3) I tested an assumption that `-Include` needs an array of wildcards, but this did not work either:

```
$files = @("*MyProgram.exe*",
           "*MyProgram.exe.config*",
           "*MyProgram.pdb*",
           "*.\XmlConfig\*.xml*")
```

---

Please advise on how to properly do `Copy-Item` in my case.

**UPDATE (based on below answers):**

I am looking for a *generic implementation* that takes an array of strings. It opens the possibility to put all necessary files/paths in one place, for easy editing, so that a non-Powershell knowledgeable person can understand and modify it as required. So in the end it would be single script to perform XCOPY deployments for any project, with input file being the only variable part. For above example, the input would look like this (saved as `input.txt` and passed as an argument to the main script):

```
MyProgram.exe
MyProgram.exe.config
MyProgram.pdb
.\XmlConfig\*.xml
```

I would prefer wildcards approach, since not many people know regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know what is wrong with filter but you can still do

```
$files | % { copy-item ..\bin\release\$_ -Destination .\test}
```

if you want to preserve directoty structure you'll have to weak this a little, like :

```
$sourcedir="c:\temp\test"
$f=@("existing.txt","hf.csv";"..\dir2\*.txt")
$f |%{
     $source=ls (join-Path $sourcedir $_) |select -expand directoryname    
     if ("$source" -like "$sourcedir*"){
        $destination=$source.Substring($sourcedir.Length)+".\" 
     }
     else{
        $destination=$_
     }  
    copy-item $sourcedir\$_ -Destination $destination -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: -Filter only takes a single string

Comment: I need to be in the target folder for this to work. But if I am in the target folder, `..\bin\release` would not work. Or `$files` need to specify absolute path which I don't want.

Comment: this is how you've done in your example... Relative path and wildcars works with my code too

Comment: If I leave your code AS IS, it creates a file with a size of a folder, so it seems like all contents is appended to one file. If I add a trailing backslash `.\test\ `, it shows this error per every file being copied: `Copy-Item : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` I tried to enclose the relevant parts in double quotes - same result.

Comment: Somehow I almost got it working as part of production script, even though it was non-cooperative in test. The only problem is that it does not keep the folder structure, so all files end up in the same folder, including those from `.\XmlConfig\ `. I tried `-Container` flag, which is supposed to preserve folder structure, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT -Include works only with file names or directory names and not combinations i.e. paths.  You can try something like this:

```
$files = 'MyProgram\.exe|MyProgram\.exe\.config|MyProgram\.pdb|XmlConfig\\.*?\.xml'

Get-ChildItem ..\bin\release -r | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.FullName -match $files)} | 
    Copy-Item -Dest .\test
```

With wildcards you could do it this way:

```
$files = @('*MyProgram.exe','*MyProgram.exe.config','*MyProgram.pdb','*\XmkConfig\*.xml')
Get-ChildItem ..\bin\release -r |
    Foreach {$fn=$_.Fullname;$_} | 
    Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($files | Where {$fn -like $_})} | 
    Copy-Item -Dest .\test
```

Comment: Is there a way to have generic implementation that takes an array of strings? I was originally thinking to put all necessary files/paths into a here string (which can be split by newline, to fit into this array-of-strings concept), or even a separate file, for easy editing, so that a non-Powershell knowledgeable person can understand and modify it as required.

Comment: Sure, that's easy.  The other issue is if you want to stick with regex patterns or the more limited wildcard patterns?  If you're OK with regex, then put each pattern on a line in a file and reconstitute $files like so: `$OFS="|"; $files = "$(get-content files.txt)"`.  Note: that particular approach won't tolerate blank lines anywhere in the file.

Comment: I would prefer wildcards, not many people know regex. Besides, expressions are not expected to be so complex to ever need regex. I can make sure input file follows some specific formatting, as long as it's easy to maintain. Could you give an example for wildcards?

Comment: @KeithHill did you mean $EOF ?

Comment: With wildcards you'll need to modify the matching logic.  I'll updated the answer here shortly.  @Kayasax, no I meant $OFS (output field separator).

Comment: Thanks for the update, same issue with it - `*\XmlConfig\*.xml` loses folder structure, so all files just end up flat in `.\test` folder. Is that normal?

Comment: Yeah, if you're copying files, it just copies the files and not the folder structure.  If you're copying folders then the folder structure is preserved with -Recurse.